# Insert a image to Latex preamble in LYX

Tags: graphics, lyx, preamble, covers

I am writing a survey report and I need used a template as a cover page from [here.](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/formal-text-rich-title-page)

It is working fine and now I need to add my university logo into that cover page. Cover page has been included in to `Latex Preamble.` Is inserting image to Latex preamble is possible? If so , how to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The template uses the macro `\titleGP` to define the title. You can use `\includegraphics` inside the definition of the macro (`\titleGP`) where it suits best.

But as always, i do not recommend using templates from this site.